# Preprocessors Directives

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I am not able to understand the output of the following code can someone please help me out?

```
#define PRODUCT(x) (x*x)
main()
{
     int i=3,j,k;
     j=PRODUCT(i++);
     k=PRODUCT(++i);
     printf("\n %d%d",j,k);
}
```

For the above I got the output as:

> 9 and 49

I am not able to understand how 49 is coming and when I commented out

```
k=PRODUCT(++i);
```

I got the output as 25.
Don't know what is going on in the program

Comment: ahhh. the perfect undefined behaviour...

Comment: When you don't understand code which contains macros, the first step is to expand them manually. (If you use macros at all, of course - which you shouldn't.)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Answer (score 1):

Macros do text substitution. `PRODUCT(i++)` expands to `(i++*i++)`. Aside from being extremely surprising that there are now two modifications of `i`, this is also undefined behavior, because the two modifications are not sequenced.